# Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64&&symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64

Tags: ios, swift, audiokit

I really don't know what happened to my program.
I used to run it successfully in 2017.
Today it goes wrong.
I try to change the build setting, build phases.They all not work.

[image]

[image]

Help me PLEASE!

Comment: Try to run in device framework doesn't support simulator

Comment: @shuo-zhao : Though am not familiar with this framework, general solution for this problem is to make sure that the framework is added in Linked framework and libraries of your target. Select your target, click general tab scroll down to see Linked framework and libraries section click + and select your framework clean and rebuild

Comment: Thank you so much for your answers!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You just need to add `-lstdc++` to the linker flags for your target. This is a new requirement since AudioKit became a static framework.

Comment: big problems always have short, but not simple solutions!!! You saved my day!! Thank you very much! it works